# Optimisation of the order of task execution

Tags: algorithm, caching, optimization

There are N tasks to execute (independent of each other). Each task uses a list of resources (known upfront), which are expensive to acquire and can be used for multiple tasks (every task has a different list, but there are overlaps). The system processes the tasks sequentially and uses a cache with a fixed size M for the resources. The cache keeps most recently used resourced only.

Problem: How to optimize the order of execution of the tasks so that we maximise the reuse of resources (i.e. we minimize the number of times we need to acquire the resources) given the size of the cache M? What would be the optimal size of the cache, i.e. minimal M such that we create every resource at most once?

The exponential solution for the problem is rather trivial, so I am after either a polynomial solution or a good approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing the problem somewhat for clarity. For the purpose of the problem:

- The problem is an set of independent tasks that can execute sequentially in any order.
- A task is needs an array of resources used in a particular order.
- The cache fits an ordered set of M resources and keeps its items on a most recently used basis.

The idea is to execute the tasks in an order which keeps the cache as stable as possible, because opening a file pointer and such is expensive.

I'm making the additional assumption that the time needed to determine the task order is immaterial (because it's fast compared to opening file pointers) or irrelevant (because the order is then cached somewhere).

Suggestions which, I hope, will seem reasonable:

- The order in which the cache is filled is important. Because M = 2 and a task using resources `[A, B, A, A, C]` will leave the cache holding `[A, C]` after one swap if starting at `[A, B]`, and another using `[C, B, A, B, C]` will leave the cache holding `[B, C]` from `[B, C]` with 2 internal swaps.
- Some tasks are more expensive than others, and we can split them in two groups: the cheap tasks are those whose number of resources is M or less; the expensive tasks are those who use more resources than that, potentially in an order such that the cache will have changed several times by the time it's completed.
- For each task, it's reasonable at first glance to take note of the first M resources used; of the last M resources used; and of how different the two are when more than M resources are needed. Even though there actually is a bit more to it than meets the eye.
- If you've any expensive tasks and can actually put them to sleep during intermediary steps where the cache changes, further optimizations become possible.

Intuitively, we'd want to order the tasks in such a way that the next task's first M resources are as close as can be from the ongoing task's last M resources:

1. Initialize the cache with exactly M resources.
2. If you can run cheap tasks, do so.
3. If you can run an expensive task, do so and goto 2.
4. If you can run a task after changing exactly one resource, do so and goto 2.
5. Repeat step 4 with two changes, three changes, etc.

Step 3 should ideally cherry pick tasks in such a way that they're doing the same kind of work as steps 4-5, and this leads us to your second question momentarily because it yields interesting insights.

The minimum cache size to avoid expensive tasks is intuitively equal to the maximum number of resources used in a single task, i.e. in order to avoid step 3 and the random states it can land you in.

The optimal cache size to avoid creating a resource more than once, however, depends on the initial state (step 1) and the permutation we pick (steps 3-4). Trivially, the two are equal in the best case scenario, and the optimum cache size is at most equal to the number of resources. An example of such a pathological case is: `[[A, B], [B, C], [C, A]]`.

Assuming you meet the minimum cache size, we can use brute force to find the optimal permutation and determine the optimal cache size; step 3 is always skipped and thus zero cost; for each candidate permutation, we assign a cost for running step 1 (= M) and steps 4-5 (= 1 per resource swapped), and compute the total cost -- interrupting the process if we've already found a better permutation.

If we don't meet the minimum cache size, we amend the procedure because we additionally need to factor in the costs involved in step 3 (= 1 per resource swapped while running the task: the order in which the swaps occur counts, so we can know nothing from the initial and final cache states).

At that stage, we should be able to compute the set of permutations with a minimum score, and pick the one that offers the lowest optimal cache size.